# Explanation of return modulo

Tags: c++, if-statement, modulo

I need some explanation about the following piece of code:

It is used for converting decimal numbers to binary numbers code:
It is from a tutorial, but it puzzles me.

```
void binary(int);

void main(void) {
int number;

cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";
cin >> number;
if (number < 0) 
    cout << "That is not a positive integer.\n";
else {
    cout << number << " converted to binary is: ";
    binary(number);
    cout << endl;
    //cin.get();
}
}

void binary(int number) {
int remainder;

if(number <= 1) {
    cout << number;
    return;
}

remainder = number%2;
binary(number >> 1);    
cout << remainder;
//cin.get();
}
```

I used breakpoint to watch the data go through the program but at the end I can't follow it.

What i see:

It takes a number and if the number  <= to 1 it prints that number (0 or 1).

But before it does it first calculate the modulus of that number and put that in remainder.
Then it moves a bit to the right of number or does the same until number is smaller or equal to 1.

But then it keeps "cout remainder" for several times (depending how much 0/1 there are calculated)
But how is this possible ?
Is remainder a buffer? (i thought it keeps overwritten(because it is int), but it looks like there keeps being bits added and then printed several times)???

Can someone explain this slowly to me ?

Comment: This question is really about recursion. Once you understand the concept of recursions, the code will make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The int is not overwritten because **it [the int] is re-allocated as an automatic variable for each time you invoke the function `binary()`** recursively, so if you invoke it `n` times recursively, you actually allocate `n` different `int`s for `remainder`.

So, it is "remembered" because they are different local variables. The allocation is usually made on the calls stack

How it works: let's have a look at the stack of an example: `binary(5)`:

```
|number=5, remainder = 1|
-------------------------
```

now, you reinvoke `binary()` with `number = 5/2=2`

```
|number=2, remainder = 0|
|number=5, remainder = 1|
-------------------------
```

and again with `number = 2/2 = 1`
now, you reinvoke `binary()` with `number = 5/2=2`, and get:

```
|number=1, remainder = 1|
|number=2, remainder = 0|
|number=5, remainder = 1|
-------------------------
```

Now, the stop condition is true, because `number <= 1` -, so you print `number` [which is 1] and pop the first element from the call stack:

```
|number=2, remainder = 0|
|number=5, remainder = 1|
-------------------------
```

and print 0, since it is the remainder at the top of the calls stack.

and do the same for the next "element" in the call stack:

```
|number=5, remainder = 1|
-------------------------
```

and print the last remainder, 1.

Answer (score 0):

Any number can be written as `sum(ai*2^i)` as well as `sum(bi*10^i)`.
I will explain for decimals as it is clearer. Given 12345,

to retrieve the digits, you do

```
12345 % 10 = 5 (op1)
12345 / 10 = 1234.5 = 1234 in a int (op2)
1234 % 10 = 4 (restart)
1234 / 10 = 123.4 = 123 in a int
```

etc...

in this case

```
op1 is equivalent to remainder = number%2; (modulo by the base)
op2 is equivalent to number >> 1; (division by the base. bitshifting is division by 2)
```

`restart` means restarting with the result of the division. That's why we have a recursive
call, using `binary(number >> 1);` Assume I call this function with `abcdef` in base 2.

```
binary(abcdef)
  binary(abcde)
     binary(abcd)
        binary(abc)
           binary(ab)
               binary(a)
                  cout << number;//a
               cout << remainer;//b 
           cout << remainer;//c
        cout << remainer;//d
     cout << remainer;//e
  cout << remainer;//f
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `binary` is a recursive function, you have something like this happening (each indent is an additional level of recursion):

```
binary call #0
calculate remainder0
    recursive binary call #1
    calculate remainder #1
        recursive binary call #2
        calculate remainder #2
            recursive binary call #3
            print number
        print remainder #2
    print remainder #1
print remainder #0
```

Recursion is used *solely* to print the remainders in reverse order of calculation, as you can see above. Do not get confused with the `number` argument -- it is irrelevant whether it's copied on each recursive call or not. You could have used a global variable just as well, and it would work (then, it would have been "modified in-place" which is what you mean by "overwritten").

The important part is that for each recursive call, the original number is shifted one bit to the right, and that's all there is to the `number` argument.

Here's the no recursion equivalent:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string binary(int);

int main(void) {
    int number;

    cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> number;
    if (number < 0)
        cout << "That is not a positive integer.\n";
    else {
        cout << number << " converted to binary is: ";
        cout << binary(number) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

string binary(int number) {
    stringstream ss;

    do {
        ss << number % 2;
        number >>= 1;
    } while (number >= 1);

    string s = ss.str();
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}
```